# Outliers in the resulting TIFF exceeding values of millions when creating a Pyramid TIFF from XYZ

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, fme-form

I'm creating TIFF files from XYZ files, which goes well and works fine.
Now I want to create pyramids (6 levels). But for some reason the statistics are all up in the millions. Minimum and maximum... Which does give me the wrong view in QGIS. When I change the values to show a correct color pallette it works fine. But that is manual and it shouldn't be working like that. Maybe it has something to do with the tiles I specify.

It seems to happen especially on the edges on the raster when zoomed out.

I used an FME writer to create the tiffs.
See image for the settings I use:
[image: FME Tiff settings]

Comment: Hi. I don't know offhand why this should happen. You could maybe try a different interleaving. I've heard one report about BIP being better than BSQ for QGIS. But ultimately, we'd need to see the output data, I think to get a better idea of what's going on. If you don't get an answer here, or don't feel comfortable posting the data here, feel free to file a support case with Safe directly. safe.com/support is the URL to go to.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for leaving a commnent! The data itself is fine. But it has something to do with the rendering of the TIFF on different pyramid levels. 
As the data itself is fine we did a little workarround to make it work for our usecase. Thanks!